# Return all the current records between date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created the following scope to return all the current records that fall in between the date range:

```
  scope :logged_between, lambda {
    where('Time.now > start_time...(Time.now < end_time)')
  }
```

controller.rb

```
   def index
     something = Model.logged_between
   end
```

I get an error `you have an error in sql syntax`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.now` doesn't look like SQL :)

```
where('? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time', Time.zone.now)
```